# How can I have my space-evenly elements stay the same position when some elements are longer in length causing other elements to move

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Im using flexbox and i have the items lined up how i want them but whenever the text is longer it will cause the other elements to move out of line. I will show in a picture what I mean.

[image]

As you can see, all the items with Cold Brew are the same text length so all of the items are lined up but the one that has longer text "Coffee Americano" causes the other elements to move. Im trying to have it where the trash icon, size select box, and price are the same position. i tried margin auto and it didnt work also i tried position absolute and that didnt work. any help is appreciated.

HTML:

```
 <div class="cartcontainer">
            <h3>Your Cart:</h3>
            <div class="cart">
                <div class="item1">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
            <p id="item1">Cold Brew</p>
            <select name="size" class="size">
                <option value="selectsize" disabled selected hidden>Size</option>
                <option value="small">S</option>
                <option value="medium">M</option>
                <option value="large">L</option>
            </select>
            <p class="price">$4.00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item2">
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
            <p id="item2">Cold Brew</p>
            <select name="size" class="size">
                <option value="selectsize" disabled selected hidden>Size</option>
                <option value="small">S</option>
                <option value="medium">M</option>
                <option value="large">L</option>
            </select>
            <p class="price">$4.00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item3">
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
            <p id="item3">Cold Brew</p>
            <select name="size" class="size">
                <option value="selectsize" disabled selected hidden>Size</option>
                <option value="small">S</option>
                <option value="medium">M</option>
                <option value="large">L</option>
            </select>
            <p class="price">$4.00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item4">
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
            <p id="item4">Cold Brew</p>
            <select name="size" class="size">
                <option value="selectsize" disabled selected hidden>Size</option>
                <option value="small">S</option>
                <option value="medium">M</option>
                <option value="large">L</option>
            </select>
            <p class="price">$4.00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item5">
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
            <p id="item5">Cold Brew</p>
            <select name="size" class="size">
                <option value="selectsize" disabled selected hidden>Size</option>
                <option value="small">S</option>
                <option value="medium">M</option>
                <option value="large">L</option>
            </select>
            <p class="price">$4.00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item6">
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
            <p id="item6">Cold Brew</p>
            <select name="size" class="size">
                <option value="selectsize" disabled selected hidden>Size</option>
                <option value="small">S</option>
                <option value="medium">M</option>
                <option value="large">L</option>
            </select>
            <p class="price">$4.00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item7">
            <a href="#" class="remove"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
            <p id="item7">Coffee Americano</p>
            <select name="size" class="size">
                <option value="selectsize" disabled selected hidden>Size</option>
                <option value="small">S</option>
                <option value="medium">M</option>
                <option value="large">L</option>
            </select>
            <p class="price">$4.00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item8">
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
            <p id="item8">Cold Brew</p>
            <select name="size" class="size">
                <option value="selectsize" disabled selected hidden>Size</option>
                <option value="small">S</option>
                <option value="medium">M</option>
                <option value="large">L</option>
            </select>
            <p class="price">$4.00</p>
        </div>
           
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
 .cartcontainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.cart {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: left;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.item1,
.item2,
.item3,
.item4,
.item5,
.item6,
.item7,
.item8 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 400px;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.size {
  width: 60px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: I’d suggest to provide a defined width to the columns. You can use the flex-basis property

Comment: You can set the `flex-basis: 70px` or `max-width: 70px` to that specific `p` tag.

Comment: Worked perfect guys, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a grid to make sure they're all equal, then you don't need to add code to every `p` or specific tag to fiddle with the alignment.  I simply added this code:

```
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
```

to your `.item1, .item2, .item3, .item4, .item5, .item6, .item7, .item8` code in the css.

take a look:

```css
 .cartcontainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.cart {

  align-items: center;
  text-align: left;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.item1,
.item2,
.item3,
.item4,
.item5,
.item6,
.item7,
.item8 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  width: 400px;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.size {
  width: 60px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cartcontainer">
            <h3>Your Cart:</h3>
            <div class="cart">
                <div class="item1">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
            <p id="item1">Cold Brew</p>
            <select name="size" class="size">
                <option value="selectsize" disabled selected hidden>Size</option>
                <option value="small">S</option>
                <option value="medium">M</option>
                <option value="large">L</option>
            </select>
            <p class="price">$4.00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item2">
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
            <p id="item2">Cold Brew</p>
            <select name="size" class="size">
                <option value="selectsize" disabled selected hidden>Size</option>
                <option value="small">S</option>
                <option value="medium">M</option>
                <option value="large">L</option>
            </select>
            <p class="price">$4.00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item3">
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
            <p id="item3">Cold Brew</p>
            <select name="size" class="size">
                <option value="selectsize" disabled selected hidden>Size</option>
                <option value="small">S</option>
                <option value="medium">M</option>
                <option value="large">L</option>
            </select>
            <p class="price">$4.00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item4">
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
            <p id="item4">Cold Brew</p>
            <select name="size" class="size">
                <option value="selectsize" disabled selected hidden>Size</option>
                <option value="small">S</option>
                <option value="medium">M</option>
                <option value="large">L</option>
            </select>
            <p class="price">$4.00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item5">
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
            <p id="item5">Cold Brew</p>
            <select name="size" class="size">
                <option value="selectsize" disabled selected hidden>Size</option>
                <option value="small">S</option>
                <option value="medium">M</option>
                <option value="large">L</option>
            </select>
            <p class="price">$4.00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item6">
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
            <p id="item6">Cold Brew</p>
            <select name="size" class="size">
                <option value="selectsize" disabled selected hidden>Size</option>
                <option value="small">S</option>
                <option value="medium">M</option>
                <option value="large">L</option>
            </select>
            <p class="price">$4.00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item7">
            <a href="#" class="remove"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
            <p id="item7">Coffee Americano</p>
            <select name="size" class="size">
                <option value="selectsize" disabled selected hidden>Size</option>
                <option value="small">S</option>
                <option value="medium">M</option>
                <option value="large">L</option>
            </select>
            <p class="price">$4.00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item8">
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
            <p id="item8">Cold Brew</p>
            <select name="size" class="size">
                <option value="selectsize" disabled selected hidden>Size</option>
                <option value="small">S</option>
                <option value="medium">M</option>
                <option value="large">L</option>
            </select>
            <p class="price">$4.00</p>
        </div>
           
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would `justify-content: center;` and apply some percentage and fixed width to the elements...

```css
.cartcontainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.cart {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: left;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.cart > div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 400px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cart > div > a {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
}
.cart > div > p {
  width: 100%;
}
.cart p.price {
  width: 30%;
  text-align: right;
}
.size {
  width: 60px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.15.3/css/fontawesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="cartcontainer">
            <h3>Your Cart:</h3>
            <div class="cart">
                <div class="item1">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
            <p id="item1">Cofee Capuccino / No suggar</p>
            <select name="size" class="size">
                <option value="selectsize" disabled selected hidden>Size</option>
                <option value="small">S</option>
                <option value="medium">M</option>
                <option value="large">L</option>
            </select>
            <p class="price">$4.00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item2">
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
            <p id="item2">Cold Brew</p>
            <select name="size" class="size">
                <option value="selectsize" disabled selected hidden>Size</option>
                <option value="small">S</option>
                <option value="medium">M</option>
                <option value="large">L</option>
            </select>
            <p class="price">$4.00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item3">
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
            <p id="item3">Bacon & Egg roll</p>
            <select name="size" class="size">
                <option value="selectsize" disabled selected hidden>Size</option>
                <option value="small">S</option>
                <option value="medium">M</option>
                <option value="large">L</option>
            </select>
            <p class="price">$14.00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item4">
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
            <p id="item4">Cold Brew</p>
            <select name="size" class="size">
                <option value="selectsize" disabled selected hidden>Size</option>
                <option value="small">S</option>
                <option value="medium">M</option>
                <option value="large">L</option>
            </select>
            <p class="price">$4.00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item5">
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
            <p id="item5">Cold Brew</p>
            <select name="size" class="size">
                <option value="selectsize" disabled selected hidden>Size</option>
                <option value="small">S</option>
                <option value="medium">M</option>
                <option value="large">L</option>
            </select>
            <p class="price">$4.00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item6">
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
            <p id="item6">Cold Brew</p>
            <select name="size" class="size">
                <option value="selectsize" disabled selected hidden>Size</option>
                <option value="small">S</option>
                <option value="medium">M</option>
                <option value="large">L</option>
            </select>
            <p class="price">$4.00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item7">
            <a href="#" class="remove"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
            <p id="item7">Coffee Americano</p>
            <select name="size" class="size">
                <option value="selectsize" disabled selected hidden>Size</option>
                <option value="small">S</option>
                <option value="medium">M</option>
                <option value="large">L</option>
            </select>
            <p class="price">$4.00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item8">
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
            <p id="item8">Cold Brew</p>
            <select name="size" class="size">
                <option value="selectsize" disabled selected hidden>Size</option>
                <option value="small">S</option>
                <option value="medium">M</option>
                <option value="large">L</option>
            </select>
            <p class="price">$4.00</p>
        </div>
           
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add max-width propety to every p tag. Try this code. If it is not your favourite, let me know.

```css
.cartcontainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.cart {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: left;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.item1,
.item2,
.item3,
.item4,
.item5,
.item6,
.item7,
.item8 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 400px;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.size {
  width: 60px;
  padding: 0px;
}
 p {
max-width: 70px;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
 <div class="cartcontainer">
            <h3>Your Cart:</h3>
            <div class="cart">
                <div class="item1">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
            <p id="item1">Cold Brew</p>
            <select name="size" class="size">
                <option value="selectsize" disabled selected hidden>Size</option>
                <option value="small">S</option>
                <option value="medium">M</option>
                <option value="large">L</option>
            </select>
            <p class="price">$4.00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item2">
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
            <p id="item2">Cold Brew</p>
            <select name="size" class="size">
                <option value="selectsize" disabled selected hidden>Size</option>
                <option value="small">S</option>
                <option value="medium">M</option>
                <option value="large">L</option>
            </select>
            <p class="price">$4.00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item3">
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
            <p id="item3">Cold Brew</p>
            <select name="size" class="size">
                <option value="selectsize" disabled selected hidden>Size</option>
                <option value="small">S</option>
                <option value="medium">M</option>
                <option value="large">L</option>
            </select>
            <p class="price">$4.00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item4">
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
            <p id="item4">Cold Brew</p>
            <select name="size" class="size">
                <option value="selectsize" disabled selected hidden>Size</option>
                <option value="small">S</option>
                <option value="medium">M</option>
                <option value="large">L</option>
            </select>
            <p class="price">$4.00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item5">
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
            <p id="item5">Cold Brew</p>
            <select name="size" class="size">
                <option value="selectsize" disabled selected hidden>Size</option>
                <option value="small">S</option>
                <option value="medium">M</option>
                <option value="large">L</option>
            </select>
            <p class="price">$4.00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item6">
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
            <p id="item6">Cold Brew</p>
            <select name="size" class="size">
                <option value="selectsize" disabled selected hidden>Size</option>
                <option value="small">S</option>
                <option value="medium">M</option>
                <option value="large">L</option>
            </select>
            <p class="price">$4.00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item7">
            <a href="#" class="remove"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
            <p id="item7" >Coffee Americano</p>
            <select name="size" class="size" >
                <option value="selectsize" disabled selected hidden>Size</option>
                <option value="small">S</option>
                <option value="medium">M</option>
                <option value="large">L</option>
            </select>
            <p class="price">$4.00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item8">
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
            <p id="item8">Cold Brew</p>
            <select name="size" class="size">
                <option value="selectsize" disabled selected hidden>Size</option>
                <option value="small">S</option>
                <option value="medium">M</option>
                <option value="large">L</option>
            </select>
            <p class="price">$4.00</p>
        </div>
           
        </div>
```